# How to get a count of new values per day in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following schema -

| Date | UserID |
| --- | --- |
| "2021-07-29" | 1 |
| "2021-07-29" | 2 |
| "2021-07-30" | 1 |
| "2021-07-30" | 4 |
| "2021-08-01" | 2 |
| "2021-08-01" | 2 |

It contains the dates of some event, along with the user who triggered that event.

I need to get a count of all the NEW users who triggered the event on every given day until today, ignoring users who have triggered the event in the past.

So after running the query, results would look like this

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| "2021-07-29" | 2 |
| "2021-07-30" | 1 |
| "2021-08-01" | 0 |

Because on the 29th, user 1, and 2 - who I've never seen before triggered it.
On the 30th, user 4 - who I've never seen before triggered it.
On the first, I've seen user 2 before, so ignore him.

Comment: Why is 2021-07-30 repeated in your result set?

Comment: @GordonLinoff was an accident

Answer (score 1):

Use `MIN()` window function to get the min date for each user and then aggregate and count for each date only the min dates:

```
SELECT Date, SUM((Date = min_date)::int) Count
FROM (
  SELECT *, MIN(date) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID) min_date
  FROM tablename
) t
GROUP BY Date;
```

Or:

```
SELECT Date, COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE Date = min_date) Count
FROM (
  SELECT *, MIN(date) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID) min_date
  FROM tablename
) t
GROUP BY Date;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9627bb3c080a21b39d72ddf4b92a611f).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function to get the first date for each user.  Then use conditional aggregation:

```
select date, count(*) filter (where seqnum = 1) as num_new_users
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the window function `FIRST_VALUE` in a subquery (or CTE) to get the first trigger for each user and in the outer query count if it's equal to the current date:

```
SELECT dt,count(*) FILTER (WHERE first_trigger = dt) 
FROM (
  SELECT *,FIRST_VALUE(dt) OVER w first_trigger FROM t
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY dt
               RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
  ORDER BY dt)j
GROUP BY dt;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bae1b842e5759e6c250ae78e4d82cc8b)